# Why execute() method of tasklet never called

Tags: java, spring-batch, tasklet

I need write simple app on spring batch. I have config + job + step structure. And inside step I use tasklet. 
The problem is: tasklet's execute() method never called.
The program runs job -> step -> create tasklet and that's all. A found many examples, which I used for that code writing, and I can't understand, what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .tasklet(new DemoTasklet())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Tasklet code:

```
import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;

public class DemoTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    public DemoTasklet() {
        System.out.println("demo tasklet constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello");
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("before");
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        System.out.println("after");
        return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
    }
}
```

And also main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(3);
        SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args);
        System.out.println(4);
    }
}
```

Please, say what is wrong, and how I should fix it.

Comment: Should `jobBuilderFactory.get("job1")` be changed to `jobBuilderFactory.get("job")` and `SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args);` to `SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);`?

Comment: i just came up with @Luca suggestion... try that and tell us if it helps

Comment: @Luca Basso Ricci it helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See @Luca Basso Ricci comment, I'm just inconsiderate. I should use:

```
 SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
```

In Main class, and missed "1" in job bean method declaration.

Comment: @user8732245 :: Could you please explain how resolved this issue.